# How to support scrolling when using pygments with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, pygments

Is it possible to use horizontal scrolling rather than text wrapping in a code section highlughted with pygments when working in Jekyll.

Source of document:

```
{% highlight bash %}

Full thread dump OpenJDK Client VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode, sharing):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0a482400 nid=0x5105 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
....
{% endhighlight %}
```

Generated page (Notice the hex address being wrapped rather than scrolled):
[image]

Comment: Not really a Jekyll/Pygments issue, but CSS. With something like `.highlight pre { white-space: pre; overflow: auto; }` should be fine. Show your generated document if you need more help.

Comment: In your CSS file. Or between `style` tags in the HTML document's `head` section.

Comment: NVM figured it out it was in the highlight.css file

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Find your highlight.css at:
/PROJECT_ROOT/assets/themes/THEME_NAME/css/highlight.css

and add this line at the end:

```
pre { white-space: pre; overflow: auto; }
```

Thanks @manatwork for the solution.

Comment: hey. by doing so.. the horizontal scroll is misbehaving. how to fix it

Comment: I eventually had to do do this to get it working correctly, not sure if it will work for you too. pre { white-space: pre; overflow: scroll; width:inherit;}

Answer (score 18):

this answer deals specifically with using pygments and jekyll on github pages

the highlighting is generated thusly:

```
<div class="highlight">
  <pre>
    <code>
      ... pygments highlighting spans ...
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

the css that will get you where you want is:

```
// -- selector prefixed to the wrapper div for collision prevention

.highlight pre code * {
  white-space: nowrap;    // this sets all children inside to nowrap
}

.highlight pre {
  overflow-x: auto;       // this sets the scrolling in x
}

.highlight pre code {
  white-space: pre;       // forces <code> to respect <pre> formatting
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'm also using bootstrap, and could never get all of the things to work together. this solved my problem! :)

Comment: At least on my Pygments implementation, there is no `<code>` tag. Removing the word `code` from the CSS solution above got everything up and running.

Answer (score 10):

I was using Jekyll and Twitter Bootstrap, and the following is what worked for me in the end:

```
.highlight pre {
    word-wrap: normal;
}

.highlight pre code {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. The problem was with `word-wrap`, not `white-space`!

Answer (score 1):

As for me, using the latest and greates Jekyll & highlighter releases, this nailed the issue:

```
/* Make code block overflow */
.highlight pre {
  display: inline-block;
}
```